# What are the different ways of using require() function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What are the different ways we can use `require()` function in Node.js
and what are the differences between them?
For example,

- `const colors = require('colors');`: *I know, this looks for the package in the `node_modules` directory*.
- `const colors = require('./colors');`
- `const colors = require('/colors');`
- `const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');`
- `const square = require('lib').square;`
- `const ep = require('./routes')(app);`
- `const { red, blue, pink } = require('colors');`
- also, include other kinds of usage which are not in the above list.

Comment: Looks like a (silly) interview question to me. Is there any practical reason why you need to know that?

Comment: forgot `require('./colors.node');` :)

Comment: There are only three things different about the use of the require function between all those examples. Everything else is about the module being required.

Comment: @georg I'm not a JavaScript mastermind. I'm just a kid who found these examples in various projects and confused myself - searched it a lot - couldn't found anything that address this specific question especially with the `@` notation - asked in stackoverflow with the best hope. Looks like you are teasing!

Answer (score 1):

require('./colors') looks for colors.js in same folder, where your file is.
And in most other cases, that you listed, parameter is only path to file.

And next ones are not related to require behaviour

```
const square = require('lib').square; //is same as
const lib = require('lib');           //1. get lib object
const square = lib.square             //2. access its property 

const ep = require('./routes')(app);    //is same as
const routesFunc = require('./routes'); //1. in routes file exports object is function
const ep = routesFunc(app);             //2.execute function with parameter

const { red, blue, pink } = require('colors'); // same as previous
const colors = require('colors);               //looks for color in node modules and returs colors object
const {red, blue, pink} = colors;              //es6 feature. Same as 
const red = colors.red;
const blue = colors.blue; 
const pink = colors.pink
```